# Ellipsize TextView at the end of the word

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am using `TextView`'s `android:ellipsize` attribute, together with `android:maxLines` to make the text fit in the maximum number of 3 lines.

The problem is that sometimes the text is cut in the middle of the word. I would like to ellipsize the text only at the end of the word. E.g.:

> Android is awesome

Now it looks like this:

> Android is awe...

But I would like it to look like this:

> Android is...

Moreover, the user can dynamically change `textSize` in this `TextView`, so it is quite hard to predict which word will be the last one.

Is there any way to ellipsize ONLY at the end of full word? If system does not allow for this, is there any library which would give such functionality or the only possibility is to write my own class which does this?

Comment: 1. get your text size; 2. get your textview size; 3. use math; 4. make appropriate changes to your text

Comment: @MocialovBoris You haven't answered my question. I have an idea on how to make my own class implementing desired functionality, but I am asking about some existing solutions which I could use in order to save my time.

Comment: That was not an attempt to answer you question, but a comment describing one approach to your problem.

Answer (score -2):

**You must specify ellipsize to 'end' for the textview. Then after setting text, add globallayout listener to textview and change its text as following:**

```
TextView articleTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.articleTitle);
        articleTitle.setText("This is a big big text");
        doEllipse(articleTitle);




 public void doEllipse(final TextView tv) {
    tv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
           tv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
           String text = tv.getLayout().getText().toString();
           int text1Index = text.indexOf("…");
           if (text1Index > 0) {
               text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(" ")) + "...";
               tv.setText(text);
           }    
        }
    });

}
```